# In DS9, is the 25th hour ever explicitly mentioned?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-ds9

In *Star Trek: Deep Space 9*, characters never fail to mention that the station (or even the Federation/Bajor/Cardassia, I'm not sure at this point) lives on a 26-hour day. There are multiple mentions of it, always in a broad and generic way.

> **SISKO:** *Sometimes I wish we could have the Defiant standing guard over the station **twenty six hours a day**.* ~ <sub><sup>[*DS9: To The Death*](http://www.chakoteya.net/DS9/496.htm)</sup></sub>

> **KIRA:** *I've had the replicator programmed with a complete Cardassian menu. You've got **twenty six hour a day computer access**, a private subspace comm. channel, and if there is anything else you need, you just ask me.* ~ <sub><sup>[*DS9: Ties of Blood and Water*](http://www.chakoteya.net/DS9/517.htm)</sup></sub>

Does any character at any point in the show explicitly state that the *current* time is 2500, or schedule a meeting at that time (or any time between 2400 and 2559)?

Comment: I'm quite certain that the answer to this is "Yes", though I don't recall off-hand. Not going to watch the entire series again (even on fast forward) to find a reference. Honestly, without someone mentioning something like, "I'm on duty until 2430", or "I'll meet you in the Holosuite at 2515", how would we even know there are more than 24 hours in a day?

Comment: @FreeMan - I think we were quite lucky to find a single canon example.

Comment: I wonder if they ever specified a reason for it. Presumably Bajor has a 26-hour day?

Comment: @PaulD.Waite - It does

Comment: There are numerous mentions of 26|52 hours where one would usually use 24|48 hours (i.e. Quark: "And my projections based on the last twenty-six hours show an unprecedented decline in profits"). Would those count?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Odo in *[DS9: Necessary Evil](https://www.st-minutiae.com/resources/scripts/428.txt)* mentions a time that uses the 26-hour clock.

> **Odo:** *The ore processor was damaged by a sub-nucleonic device **at twenty five hundred hours** last night. It'll be out of operation for two weeks.*

This aligns with what we know about Bajor;

> The Class-M homeworld of the humanoid Bajoran race is Earth-like in
> appearance with large, blue oceans and seas that appear a little more
> greenish than Earth's from orbit. **A "day" is a 26-hour rotation on its
> axis,** and it has at least five moons, although two may be rogues.
>
> <sub><sup>[Startrek.com Database Article - Bajor](https://web.archive.org/web/20100729214021/http://www.startrek.com/database_article/bajor)</sup></sub>

---

Inerestingly, it's not clear whether these are twenty-six *Bajoran hours* or twenty-six *Earth hours*. None of the show's writers seem overly keen to explain it, and this is frequently contradicted by the Extended Universe novels.

> Picard stared into the distance, his attention focused somewhere
> between the bright sun and the dark object. **“The Bajoran day is
> twenty-five standard hours,** so the sun’s apparent motion is slower
> than we’re used to.” His forehead wrinkled in thought. “No, it’s moved
> a greater distance than an atmospheric refraction would have in the
> same time.”
>
> <sub><sup>[TOS: Captain's Peril](https://breezewiki.com/memory-beta/wiki/Captain%27s_Peril)</sup></sub>

Comment: OP is unclear about the scope of the 25-hour clock's adoption,  so maybe you should clear that up.

Comment: @Spencer - I've added some extra bumf. It's inconsistently referenced, even from episode to episode so It not the easiest to pin down.

Comment: I've always been under the assumption that when time is discussed in Star Trek, it's using Earth based time (as that's were the Federation HQ is), and the Universal Translator takes care of converting everything to each individual's reference time.   An example that comes to mind the conversation between Dax and a Jem'Hadar soldier (I think in DS9: The Quickening), about their ages, how Jem'Hadar never live past 30, and Dax stopped counting at 300.

Comment: @RisingZan - I'm assuming most Class M planets will have a similar orbital period. Years might be a few months plus or minus.

Comment: Is it possible that since they're using "hours" in the first place, and not some other Bajoran-derived unit of time, the "26 hours" is referring to 26 Earth hours? We count the days of other planets in our solar system using Earth hours, after all. And since the Federation and Starfleet are headquartered on Earth, a number of different systems are coordinated based on Earth's standards. I know the novel excerpt contradicts that, but since it's from the extended universe, it isn't necessarily the most definitive or reliable source.

Comment: @SovereignInquiry - It's not clear at all, and treated inconsistently in the show and the books. Closest I can find to a real answer is Picard saying that their day is approx 25 'standard hours', but that's just one author. I strongly suspect it was just a throwaway line and never intended to be explored in any real depth.